# How to create flexible onbuild docker image that uses env vars?

Tags: docker, docker-onbuild

I have a base `onbuild` tagged docker image that I would like to use as a template for builds but I want the child image to be able to set an ENV var to modify the ONBUILD instructions

base-onbuild:

```
FROM root-image

RUN mkdir -p /app/src
UNBUILD COPY . /app/src/
ONBUILD WORKDIR /app/src
ONBUILD RUN ./build ${TARGET_APP}
ONBUILD RUN cp ${TARGET_APP}/build/bin /app/bin
```

my-app:

```
FROM base-onbuild

ENV TARGET_APP my-app
CMD my-app
```

According to the docker documentation the `ONBUILD` steps get run immediately *after* the `FROM base-onbuild` clause, so before the `ENV` statement that sets `TARGET_APP` so in the `ONBUILD` steps `TARGET_APP` is not set.

I have also tried to pass the `TARGET_APP` value via the `--build-args` argument of `docker build` but this also didn't have any effect.

Is there another way that I can set variables and modify the `UNBUILD` steps?

similar question: [Placeholder field for the ONBUILD section for child docker images to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451872/placeholder-field-for-the-onbuild-section-for-child-docker-images-to-use)

Answer (score 3):

### Mandatory arg

I have something that works for the case in your question, but it won't work for all cases in general.

In your dockerfile after `ONBUILD WORKDIR /app/src`, you'll have:

```
COPY build_copy.sh /config
ONBUILD COPY target_app.txt /config
ONBUILD RUN sh /config/build_copy.sh
```

The file build_copy.sh will contain the following lines:

```
TARGET_APP=`cat /config/target_app.txt`
ONBUILD RUN ./build $TARGET_APP
ONBUILD RUN cp $TARGET_APP/build/bin /app/bin
```

The file target_app.txt should contain the text you wanted to put into TARGET_APP.
This will require you to have a file target_app.txt in your child image.

---

### Optional arg

You can somewhat mitigate this by using putting 'optional' text files in a folder /config in your child root and changing your ONBUILD to:

```
ONBUILD COPY /config /config
```

You'll only need the folder then, all files in there would be optional. The shell script can then use:

```
TARGET_APP_2=`cat /config/target_app.txt`
if [ -n "$TARGET_APP_2" ]
then
  TARGET_APP=$TARGET_APP_2
else
  TARGET_APP='default_app'
fi
```